# Можно ли писать одну программу на нескольких языках?

Tags: java, erlang

Я начал изучать функциональное программирование. Пока в основном по книге СИКП. Видно, что это крутая штука. Когда нет управления состоянием - ФП по-моему очень облегчает написание кода, позволяет сосредоточиться на алгоритме. Но мне вот очень интересно, а можно ли вообще писать одну и ту же программу на разных языках? Делают ли так? Например, писать все в императивном стиле - это по-моему не самая лучшая идея. Но и в функциональном стиле вряд ли получится целиком большую программу написать. То есть функциональны и императивный подход точно должны сосуществовать в больших программах, правильно? А вот что насчет языка? Например, GUI и обращения к базе данных реализовать на java, а всю бизнес-логику на erlang? Нет, сейчас конечно можно писать в функциональном стиле и на java, но столько фишек как на erlang все равно не получишь. Например, erlang дает очень большие возможности для распараллеливания. На java, даже используя добавленные недавно лямбда таких возможностей для распараллеливания не добиться. В общем, интересует следующее: возможно ли технически в одном проекте писать часть на erlang, а другую на java?

Comment: А вам нужно серьезное распаралелливание для бизнес логики ? Там могут быть счетные задачи, но распаралеливать их больше чем процессоров в системе нет никакого смысла

Comment: Может лучше взять scala и совмещать ООП с ФП в рамках одного языка как душе угодно?

Comment: @Mike, А если, например, многопользовательская игра?

Comment: @Nofate, почему тогда не Clojure? К тому же, ни Scala, ни Clojure как я знаю, такой возможности для распараллеливания не предоставляют как erlang

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров И вообще очень странный подход gui и обращения к базе в java, а некая бизнес логика отдельно сама по себе. что будет делать бизнес логика в стороне от канала java-БД ? Бизнес логика как раз должна контролировать обращения к базе и скрывать их от GUI, дабы контролировать весь процесс

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров Вы посмотрите как реализованы высоконагруженные сетевые приложения, например web-сервера nginx тот же. Он достаточно удачен в плане производительности. При этом у него процессов/потоков веркеров запускается с десяток и они обслуживают массу запросов. поток слишком дорогое удовольствие что бы плодить его ради каждого подключенного пользователя

Comment: Почему бы и нет. Получаем распределенное приложение, возможно на нескольких компах, отдельные процессы которого общаются через сокеты, общую память и т.п.

Comment: @avp, ну да, я про распределенные и говорю. И про те, у которых высокие требования к отказоустойчивости. В erlang же нет никаких "world stop", код можно менять не перезапуская приложение. Ну я тут кончено не хотел разводить холивар про erlang) По-моему уже для многих очевидно что некоторое задачи на этом языке можно здорово выполнять. Но по-моему писать программу целиком на erlang тоже не гуд. Там мало либ. Вот я и спрашиваю, можно ли совместить erlang и Java? а как это с технической точки зрения возможно, подскажите?

Comment: Или лучше все-таки Clojure использовать. Хотя как совместить Clojure и Java я тоже не знаю(

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров Тогда может стоит переформулировать вопрос в ключе "Как технически обеспечить взаимодействие компонентов на java и erlang". А вообще универсального рецепта "делаем все на этом наборе языков" быть не может. Все зависит от специфики проекта. У меня есть система у которой основная бизнес логика на Oracle, web на perl, немного JS, несколько отдельных компонент на C, так же на C специализированный модуль ядра linux и еще некоторая часть на shell скриптах. И такая  связка вряд ли понадобится для решения несколько иных задач

Comment: @Mike, сначала и хотел спросить как технически. Но был не уверен что так вообще делают)

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров Я думаю если взять все множество языков и технологий, сделать из них многомерную матрицу, то на каждом пересечении в этой матрице найдутся проекты сделанные на такой связке :) Есть конечно распространенные связки, но есть и экзотика.

Comment: @Mike, а какие распространенные, подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров Ну вот это не ко мне, лучше в инете поискать. Мне всегда везло на экзотику, о которой вы скорее всего ничего не слышали :)

Comment: Про erlang ничего не могу сказать, а вот связки C/Python/Java/Shell, C/Tcl и C/Java/Shell видел. Правда, Java всюду использовалась для web-интерфейса админов к конфигам/базе данных и  использовала sh скрипты для передачи чего-либо другим процессам.

Comment: На Erlang есть возможность написать порт и вызывать функции из программы, написанной на других языках. Для Java есть  JInterface, можете почитать статью [Integrating Java and Erlang -Интеграция Java и Erlang](http://xt84.blogspot.com/2008/09/integrating-java-and-erlang-java-erlang.html). + обратите внимание на [эту](https://github.com/fredlund/JavaErlang) библиотеку.

Answer (score 7):

Не вижу ничего плохого в том, чтобы писать программу на нескольких языках, каждую часть — на том, на котором удобнее. Вопрос стоит больше в том, удобно ли компоновать части, написанные на различных языках.

Например, если языки, которые вы используете, опираются на общий рантайм, объединять их легко (особенно если при этом языки создаются с рассчётом на interoperability). Пример: языки на основе .NET (C#, Visual Basic, F#), языки на основе JVM (Java + Scala), языки на основе C (C + C++): объекты одного из них можно без особенного труда использовать в других.

С сильно разнородными языками связать модули сложнее. Обычно используют либо C в виде общего знаменателя (Python, P/Invoke в .NET), либо обмен данными через текстовый формат (Unix shell и его утилиты). Также часто применяются различные формы RPC (например, AJAX по сути является таковым, и не стоит забывать COM).

Ещё одна часто используемая возможность — полная или частичная кодогенерация. Например, Razor генерирует HTML, T4 и WPF генерируют исходники на C#.

---

По сути, сейчас и так многие программы пишутся на нескольких языках. Например, если вы пишете веб-сайт на чём-то наподобие ASP.NET MVC, то вы используете C#, Razor, HTML, Javascript и возможно Typescript в одном проекте.

Comment: так это frontend/backend, разве нет? А я имею ввиду backend на нескольких языках?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: А в чём разница?

Comment: я недостаточно компетентен, но все же попробую. HTML, например, предоставляет удобные средства для смешивания кода на разных языках (php, например, вообще одной строчкой можно подсунуть). А вот совместить Java и erlang наверное не так легко?

Comment: Ну, HTML _генерируется_ кодом на PHP. Точно так же можно на Erlang, например, генерировать код на Java, компилировать и запускать.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Или процесс на Java может генерировать данные и подавать их на вход процессу на Erlang, и принимать оттуда готовый результат.

Comment: оу, круто! Не знал, спасибо) Подскажите, куда тут копать? JNI?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Pipe, или через обыкновенный текстовый файл? JNI наверное не так уж необходимо. Хотя, всё зависит от того, какую архитектуру вы придумаете.

Comment: про Pipe очень интересно, надо поразбираться с этим, спасибо!)

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Большинство юниксовских утилит командной строки связываются друг с другом через pipe. Так что нет причин, по которой и вы не сможете связать таким образом несколько процессов.

Comment: а через текстовый файл... тут JSON подойдет?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Можно и JSON. Что угодно можно, вы тут полный хозяин. JSON можно, кстати, и через pipe передавать.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров если не доходить до общего рантайма, то в System V есть три вида IPC (не считая пайп), что уже будет довольно низкоуровнево и должно бегать предельно быстро.

Answer (score 6):

Можно. Попробуйте язык [Katahdin](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katahdin)

> Katahdin представляет язык программирования просто как инструмент, не
>   ограничивая программиста в выборе платформы или библиотек. Каждый
>   участок программы, отвечающий за конкретную задачу, может быть
>   реализован на более подходящем языке программирования (в зависимости
>   от задачи, разработчиков и используемых библиотек).
>
> Например, программа на Фортране, предназначенная для вычислений, может
>   плохо справляться с некоторой обработкой текста, требуемой при
>   вводе-выводе. В этом месте лучше использовать более подходящий язык,
>   например, Perl. В программе на Katahdin код, обрабатывающий текст и
>   написанный на Perl, может быть использован в том же файле, что и
>   программа на Фортране.

Comment: Ого, очень интересно, спасибо!